# Does Magento2 cancel orders after 2 hours?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

We are seeing a few orders in our sales list that are 'Cancelled' and when we look at them, the reason for authorization failed is: "You have to enter the card holder name."

I thought this was a bit odd because Magento does not let you progress to the payment page without first entering a first and last name (which passes through automatically to the payment page)

We are using a Sagepay extension to process payments so I asked those developers why the autorization failed on those orders.

They say that Magento creates orders before the payment is executed. This means that if the customer enters wrong data or doesn't even enter any info, Magento sets a corresponding status and cancels the order after 2 hours.

This behaviour is most probably caused by the users themselves, by leaving the payment page without explicitly cancelling the transaction.

Is this true that Magento cancels the order after 2 hours? (I cant seem to find any information regarding this) If so can this timeout be increased?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a cron task responsible of that

```
<job name="sales_clean_orders" instance="Magento\Sales\Model\CronJob\CleanExpiredOrders" method="execute">
    <schedule>0 * * * *</schedule>
</job>
```

You can check what it does, looking in **vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/CronJob/CleanExpiredOrders.php** file

```
public function execute()
{
    $lifetimes = $this->storesConfig->getStoresConfigByPath('sales/orders/delete_pending_after');
    foreach ($lifetimes as $storeId => $lifetime) {
        /** @var $orders \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection */
        $orders = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create();
        $orders->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $storeId);
        $orders->addFieldToFilter('status', Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT);
        $orders->getSelect()->where(
            new \Zend_Db_Expr('TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at`)) >= ' . $lifetime * 60)
        );

        try {
            $orders->walk('cancel');
            $orders->walk('save');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error('Error cancelling deprecated orders: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, you can edit default cancel time in backoffice parameter **Stores > Configuration > Sales > Sales > Orders Cron Settings**

Comment: Thanks Raul great info - I couldnt seem to find a setting in back office though? Is it Stores > Configuration > Sales > Sales > Orders Cron Settings?

Comment: Yes, it is... feel free to flag answer as valid if it helped ;)